# Phonegap + sencha touch animated splash screen

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, sencha-touch-2, cordova-2.0.0

So i have a PNG of a jet engine and i would like this to be the splash screen to my app, works fine with a static PNG but how can i animate this jet engine to have a clock-wise rotation and then fade or disappear when the app is ready?

At the moment i use phonegap splash screen and in my index.html i check when the device is ready and hide the splash screen. Works great.

I am using cordova 2.0.1 + Android SDK + Sencha Architect

Is it possible to do any sort of smooth-ish animation?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve it i am in need of it...